# ASP.NET: Custom Control Reloads Whole Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a ASP.NET site with C# code.
Now the trouble starts when I create a custom control programmatically. The control displays in a panel, but when I click one of the buttons of the control it does nothing. If I click them twice, the user control disappears.
Using the debugger, I found that it's doing a postback, which is strange because I tried using buttons and setting the `usesubmitbehavior` to `false`; it's still sending postbacks.

Here is where the control is inserted on the `default.aspx` file

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="contentHolderUpdatePanel"
                UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="contentPanel">
       </asp:Panel>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the ASPX from `ListadoAuditoria` of the control.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="auditorTableUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Table runat="server" ID="auditorTable" BorderWidth="0" Width="100%">
         <asp:TableHeaderRow HorizontalAlign="Center">
             <asp:TableHeaderCell>Button
             </asp:TableHeaderCell>
         </asp:TableHeaderRow>
     </asp:Table>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="formHolderUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="testLabel" Text="bbbbbbbbbbbbb" ></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The method that the button invokes should change the text of the label `testLabel` from "bbbbbbbbbbbbb" to "aaaaaaaaaaa". Obviously I'm doing an `auditorTableUpdatePanel.Update()` after I modify the text.

The control CS

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadAudits();
    }

    public void loadAudits()
    {

        for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();

            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();

            ImageButton deleteButton = new ImageButton();
            deleteButton.ImageUrl = "~/image.gif";
            deleteButton.Click += generateNewPart;
            deleteButton.EnableViewState = true;
            deleteButton.ID = i.ToString();

            cell1.Controls.Add(deleteButton);

            row.Cells.Add(cell1);

            auditorTable.Rows.Add(row);

        }
    }

    public void generateNewPart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tumadre.Text = "aaaaaaaaaaaa";
        formHolderUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
```

And here is the code when I generate the control and insert it into the panel:

```
Panel panel = (Panel)Page.FindControl("contentPanel");
UpdatePanel updatePanel = (UpdatePanel)Page.FindControl("contentHolderUpdatePanel");
ListadoAuditorias listadoAuditorias = (ListadoAuditorias)LoadControl("~/CargaDeAuditoria/ListadoAuditorias.ascx");
panel.Controls.Add(listadoAuditorias);
updatePanel.Update();
```

I looked over the Internet and didn't found anything.

Comment: Neither `contentPanel` or `contentHolderUpdatePanel` exist in the html you've posted.

Comment: I can put the html where it is, if its necesary

Comment: What would be best is if you can recreate the problem with a very simple example, so it's easier for people to see what's going on. You'll get more help that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where exactly the code to dynamically add the controls is, but it must be called on EVERY postback to re-add the controls.  You can't just add it once and forget about it.  When you postback, the page will re-render with the markup in your aspx page (which does not have your dynamic controls, obviously).  The values from the dynamically added controls will still be in ViewState, but the controls will not be re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking at; I don't know if the "code of the control" is the code for the ListadoAuditorias control that you're loading.  If so, I didn't notice any buttons.

So I could be wrong here, but the first thing that pops out at me is that it looks like you're loading the ListadoAuditorias control and then adding it to a normal Panel control.  If one of the controls inside of ListadoAuditorias triggers a postback, and it's not contained within an UpdatePanel, then yes, I'd expect the page to do a postback and reload, unless you have specified the ChildrenAsTriggers and UpdateMode properties to be something other than their default values (I think).  So I would just suggest that you take a look at where you are adding your controls.  Make sure that they're contained within an UpdatePanel, if that's what your intention is.

Also, note that the UseSubmitBehavior property of the Button control does not prevent the button from initiating a postback.  That property only determines whether the button gets rendered as `<input type="submit" />` or `<input type="button" />`.  In the latter case (when you set UseSubmitBehavior to false) the control still renders javascript in the HTML element's onclick attribute to cause a postback.

EDIT: I've amended my explanation regarding UpdatePanel control to mention the ChildrenAsTriggers and UpdateMode properties.

Comment: i edited my post to put all the code of the control and the default.aspx